# Parsing multipart requests with different controllers

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a need where multiple http requests are batched into one http post like so:

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*  
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch  
Connection:keep-alive  
Content-Length:604  
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=1408785817122  
Host:localhost:8080  
Origin:null

--1408785817122
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

GET /api/products HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:8080  
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*


--1408785817122
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

POST /api/users/2 HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:8080  
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
```

Some data for team 2 goes here.

```
--1408785817122
Content-Type: application/http; msgtype=request

PUT /api/products HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:8080  
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*  
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

"{\"Name\":\"Product X\",\"StockQuantity\":300}"

--1408785817122--
```

I have jars server-side that were included from different teams. Each team included jars that have their own controllers. Team 1 needs to respond to the 1st part, Team 2 to the 2nd and so on. I need to return a single multipart response where each boundary contains the response from each designated controller with either 200 or any other status code and data it deems correct.

1. So the controllers dispersed across different jars need to get scanned and loaded by the process
2. As the multipart request comes in, the right controller needs to be invoked
3. Single multipart response needs to be returned containing success or failed responses from all controllers.

Is this feasible with any spring project? Preferably spring mvc.

Please point me in the right direction

Comment: I am curious - how do you generate such a request. I can imagine bunching multiple request bodies(say file content) together this way, but this is different from what I have done before - batching actual http requests together. AFAIK, I don't think Spring MVC natively provides this support, I can imagine adding in a custom orchestration controller though, that can take in this request and in-turn dispatches to different controllers(or services) and aggregates it back.

Comment: The request is generated via js. Certain urls are registered for specific workflows. So the js knows that before submitting, 3 urls will be hit so it intercepts and combines all into 1.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part here is that as all those requests are transmitted as multipart element in an aggregated request, one single controller will receive a real HttpRequest, containing *files* containing text for requests, and its job would be to parse the text for each part, doing what normally Tomcat and DispatcherServlet do !

The only way I imagine would be that this controller opens a low level Socket connection to the tomcat server (ie on port 8080), sends separatly the differents parts, gets the different *text of* responses (and not HttpResponseS), concatenates them as a mime multipart object and sends that back as the body of its own response. You still have to choose between serial operations (one part after the other on a single connection), parallel operation (one part on its own connection) or a mix with a pool on connections processing the requests.

But it would be a very low level component, with little relation with the actual service.

Edit per comment :

At the beginning, I thought that it could be enough to call the `service` method of `DispatcherServlet`. But it is not that easy because :

- I do not know how to find the configured `DispatcherServlet`, but can only get its `RequestDispatcher` - ok calling the include method could be enough, but a bit tricky
- you need to manually parse the HTTP protocol to generate a `HttpServletRequest` (and also generated from scratch a `HttpServletResponse`), what is normally done by the container.

That's the reason why I fell to the solution of a low level socket which seems paradoxically more straightforward

Comment: Right on. I was thinking that may be DispatcherServlet would be responsible for seeing any request that comes to */batch and dispatch each part in the multipart request in a sync, parallel or async manner (configurable) to all controllers with a set SLA (wait for x ms and if a specific request is not returned, respond with a timeout for that part in multipart) that will also be configurable. So if 3 parts are sent and if 2 respond within x ms but the 3rd is taking longer, return a multipart response with 2 parts containing data and one part that has a timeout. All should be configurable though

Comment: Just need a solution though. Should it be a DispatcherServlet, Filter or something else? And what are the impl details?

Comment: Thanks. I also saw a MultipartResolver (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartResolver.html). Could that somehow help us out?

Comment: @TimJohnson: The `MultipartResolver` **must** be used, but it only split the multipart in *sequential files*, but will not convert them to `ServletRequest` objects.